# Creating custom validator reactive form from regular expression angular

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-reactive-forms

I have some regular expression validation that I use on email form, this is how it looks

```
this.customerForm = this.fb.group({
      email: [null, {
        Validators.pattern('^[^\\s@]+@[^\\s@]+\\.[^\\s@]{1,}$')],updateOn: 'blur'
      }]
    });
```

Validation work fine, but what i need is to make custom validator for this regular expression, any idea how to start, thanks

I have tried like this

```
properEmailValidator(): ValidatorFn {
    const nameRe = /^[^\\s@]+@[^\\s@]+\\.[^\\s@]{1,}$/;
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
      const forbidden = nameRe.test(control.value);
      return forbidden ? { emailNotValid: { value: control.value } } : null;
    };
  }
```

But this does not work:(

Comment: You can find the guide from the Angular Docs on how to do it [here](https://angular.io/guide/form-validation#defining-custom-validators)

Comment: I have updated the question, and tried but i dont have luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you define the expresion as a string, you have to escape the backslashes, as you properly did in the `Validators.pattern('^[^\\s@]+@[^\\s@]+\\.[^\\s@]{1,}$')`.

But if you define the expresión as a proper `RegExp` as you are doing in the validator function, you must not do it, as it would try to match it as a backslash character. So you need to modify your `RegExp` as follows.

```
const nameRe = /^[^\s@]+@[^\s@]+\.[^\s@]{1,}$/;
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are using reactive form, then you can put it directly when you are creating the form.

```html
filterForm: FormGroup;

filterForm = formBuilder.group({
  firstName: [null],
  lastName: [null],
  zipCode: [null, [Validators.pattern('[0-9]{5}')]]
});
```